# Android launch app show "Can modify system settings" dialog

Tags: android, android-permissions

I write a simple demo , test a third-party push SDK.

When I launch my demo , system shows me a dialog like this.
But the dialog doesn't show up below Android 6.0

[image]

How to avoid it when I launch my app except allowing the permission request?

Comment: Starting from Android 6.0 some permissions are not granted anymore automatically  instead user should allow it.

Comment: I have given the WRITE_SETTINGS , still unable to  the static IP . Please find my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150511/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-cannot-keep-your-settings-in-the-secure . Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like my third-party SDK request the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission programmatically and launch the “Can modify system settings” dialog.

Comment: I have given the WRITE_SETTINGS , still unable to  the static IP . Please find my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150511/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-cannot-keep-your-settings-in-the-secure . Please help me

Answer (score 2):

As per marshmallow and onwards,the app is not allowed the permissions at the time of installation. Rather, the system will ask for required permission at the time in need(only one time if granted).In older versions(<23), apps were granted all required permissions at the time of installation.

Can modify system settings:

This is another new access setting. This is used to do things like read your current settings, turn on Wi-Fi, and change the screen brightness or volume. It's another permission that isn't in the permissions list.

Comment: Is there any particular permission that can cause this “Can modify system settings” dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Might u have use on wifi programmatically or anything like this. Which gets block. Pls check ur any of this like functionality